# ASP.NET membership create users, logging in works. But then it doesn't?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have a application that connects to a remote sql server. I am able to create users and they are stored in the DB. Then I can go to the login page and login. But after a while, I am unable to log in and it just sits at the login page. The user is still in the DB

Help?

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LoginSQL" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;UID=xxxxx;pwd=xxxx;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="Login" loginUrl="Default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="20"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <membership defaultProvider="MySqlLoginProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="MySqlLoginProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="LoginSQL" applicationName="Login" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" passwordAttemptWindow="30" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ASPRoles" cookiePath="/" cookieTimeout="60" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieProtection="All">
      <providers>
        <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LoginSQL" applicationName="Login"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: what does the serverside code that authenticates and logs in your user look like?

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LoginSQL" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;UID=xxxxx;pwd=xxxxx;"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="Login" loginUrl="Default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="20"/>
    </authentication>

Comment: Server side code? All I did was run aspnet_regsql to set up the tables. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: I cant see something wrong in ur web.config file, try to increase the timeout="20" ,

Comment: try this one : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/custom_authentication.aspx or http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/BuildingWebSite.aspx

Comment: I know about the timeout. But if I go back to the login screen say in 2 hours with a user id and password that is still in the database. I am unable to login. Increasing the timeout probably won't fix the overall problem??