# ASP.NET Membership. Create user works, but cannot log in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm using the createwizard connected to a remote SQL DB. The user creates fine and shows up in the DB.

I also have the login control, but after I put in the username and password, I am unable to login, it just sits at the login screen. What do I need to look into?

I went through asp.net config utility and set the directory that holds my auth/member pages to deny anyone who is unauth.

source code for login

```
<%@ Page Title="Login" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Account/LoginMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="BT4SGWebApplication.Account.Login" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div style="border-style: none; border-width: thin; height: 565px; top: -3px; left: -5px; width: 922px; position: relative;">
        <div style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; height: 370px; width: 360px; top: 95px; left: 420px; position: absolute">
            <asp:Login ID="LoginField" runat="server" 


                style="position: absolute; top: 89px; left: 71px; height: 132px; width: 217px" 
                MembershipProvider="MySqlLoginProvider">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                            Log In</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                                ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                                                ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="LoginField">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                                ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." 
                                                ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="LoginField">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" Text="Remember me next time." />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                            <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                            <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" 
                                                ValidationGroup="LoginField" PostBackUrl="~/Tabs/Home.aspx" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>
            </asp:Login>
            <asp:Label ID="loginLabel" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" 
                Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="XX-Large" 
                style="height: 42px; width: 100px; top: 30px; left: 128px; position: absolute; border-style: solid; border-width: thin" 
                Text="Log In"></asp:Label>
            <asp:PasswordRecovery ID="PasswordRecovery1" runat="server" 

                style="top: 253px; left: 28px; position: absolute; height: 102px; width: 304px">
            </asp:PasswordRecovery>
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" 
            BorderWidth="8px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="X-Large" 
            style="top: 233px; left: 150px; height: 53px; width: 232px; position: absolute; border-style: solid; border-width: thin" 
            Text="Click to Register" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

web.config

```
<configuration>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="LoginSQL" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;UID=xxxx;pwd=xxxxx;"/>
    </connectionStrings>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies></compilation>

        <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name="Login" loginUrl="Default.aspx" timeout="20" />
  </authentication>

  <membership defaultProvider="MySqlLoginProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="MySqlLoginProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="LoginSQL" applicationName="/" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" passwordAttemptWindow="30" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"/>
            </providers>
        </membership>

        <profile>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
            </providers>
        </profile>

        <roleManager cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ASPRoles"
   cookieTimeout="60" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">

   <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="LoginSQL" applicationName="/" name="MyRoleProvider"
     type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
   </providers>

  </roleManager>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does the browser's login attempt ever timeout? If so, what's the full timeout message? That'll likely be more valuable that your web.config.

Comment: Nope, just a fast click and the username and pass that were in the fields are erased. Still just sits on the login page.

Comment: It is likely a problem with your login page / control.  Can you post the code for your login page?

Comment: Okay. I posted the login page source code. The web.config is below that. Anyone?

Comment: Typing in a destination page url doesn't work. Why? I renamed the pages and that works. Upon Auth, does it always go to the default page?  No way to change that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET membership create users, logging in works. But then it doesn't?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998581/asp-net-membership-create-users-logging-in-works-but-then-it-doesnt)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to confirm that the ReturnUrl querystring argument isn't pointing you back to the login page. Also try specifying the DestinationPageUrl property on the login control itself.

**Update** Looking at your code this is the problem. You're being redirected by default to default.aspx, which is your login page. Either rename the login page to login.aspx or specify the redirect page manually as described above.